# How to include .m4 files in Autoconf?

Tags: autoconf

I have downloaded a macro from Autoconf Archive, and I want to use it. What do I have to put in my configure.ac file to make use this macro?

Answer (score 39):

You may want to add AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR to `configure.ac` to the directory where the macro is:

```
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([path/to/macros])
```

You'll need to invoke the macro somewhere in this file also.

and in `Makefile.am` you'll probably need to set up ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS (if you are using automake):

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS         = -I path/to/macros
```

Then invoke `autoreconf -fvi` and you should be set.

Answer (score 12):

I had this exact same question, and it was harder to find an answer than I thought. It looked like `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR` was what I wanted, but if you are not using libtoolize, it appears that `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR` is useless at present.

If you're using automake, I think the answer above is right.

I'm not using automake, so the only way I've found is to use the `m4_include` macro to suck in each .m4 file individually. I found this approach here:

http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/autoconf/macros.html

Hope this helps. (Considering how long autoconf has been around, it boggles my mind somewhat that there's no built-in way to just specify a directory in the .ac file. Seems like it would be an awefully common use case. Oh, well.)

Comment: "if you are not using libtoolize, it appears that `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR` is useless at present." Why? I haven't found any documentation that suggests any association between MACRO_DIR and libtoolize.

Comment: @underscore_d It's been a while, so I don't remember for sure, but I think it was by experiment that I discovered this.

Comment: Running libtoolize will create symlinks in the directory specified by AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, provided you DON'T use m4_include for certain things because libtoolize fails to follow such includes (see my Q/A here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340633/implement-inclusion-of-another-file-into-a-stream-read-from-stdin

Comment: Using a `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([. macro])` directive plus `autoreconf` made the system create a `aclocal.m4` which automatically writes all the necessary imports.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to Idav1s' solution (which is absolutely correct), you can install the macro in a location where `aclocal` will find it (use `aclocal --print` to see where `aclocal` is looking for `.m4` files). Each approach has pros and cons. If you install the `.m4` files in `$(aclocal --print)`, you can use the macro in all of your projects without doing anything else.  The primary drawback is that each developer who works on the project will have to install the macro on their box, and that requires each developer to have a reasonable understanding of the autotools.

Comment: Sorry, I have never used autoconf. How do you "you can install the macro" there?

Comment: Just copy the .m4 file that defines the macro into one of the directories that aclocal knows about.  You can get the list of directories with `aclocal --print`

Answer (score 4):

I have this issue as well, and just fixed it. My environment is: **CentOS 6.4, M4 1.4.17 , autoconf 2.69, libtool 2.4, automake 1.14**

Here are the steps I used.

```
add m4 as AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR to your configure.ac
rm aclocal.m4  if it exists
mkdir m4       if it does not exist
# copy some dummy files into the folder 
# or some versions of autoconf  won't work   
autoreconf -i --install
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it enough to just save the m4 macro in certain directory and run `autoreconf` with the `-I` option:

```
autoreconf -i -I/path/to/your/m4/file
```

Or did I misunderstand you and do you want to integrate it permanently, without the person running `autoreconf` to worry about downloading the m4 file?